# the table is not updated, it only does "insert" to the text i put in the textbox

Tags: asp.net

The table is not updated, it only does "insert" to the text I put in the textbox. Can someone tell me what's wrong? Here is my code:

```
protected void update_b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Update employee details

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "update employees set Emp_number='" + emp_num.Text + "',First_name='" + emp_fname.Text + "', Last_name='" + emp_lname.Text + "',Phone_num='" + emp_phone.Text + "',Email='" + emp_email.Text + "'where Emp_number='" + emp_num.Text + "'";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("employee details updated successfuly");

        emp_num.Text = "";
        emp_fname.Text = "";
        emp_lname.Text = "";
        emp_phone.Text = "";
        emp_email.Text = "";

        Bind1();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean your update query inserting rows?

Comment: Is there text in all these textboxes??

Comment: when i'm trying to update employee details by emp_num, where ever i dont write anything its uptade me null, empty